# Visual Studio Code: Run node script on save

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code (1.8.1) to write ECMAScript 6 for NodeJS 7.3 (so currently *no* TypeScript).

I want to run the current script with node from the command line (`node ${file}`) *every time the script file is saved*. Is this possible?

To be clear: NodeJS is not running as server, but used for executing cli scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'run-when-changed' module to achieve this.

You can use it like:

> run-when-changed --watch "src/**" --exec "npm run build"

This will watch file changes in src folder and execute npm build script.

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-when-changed

Answer (score 6):

```
npm install nodemon --save

nodemon myFile.js
```

`nodemon` package - provides monitoring for any changes in your node.js file and automatically restart it

Comment: nodemon keeps the NodeJS process running, is not it? For now, this is not a problem. But the solution i am looking for is to run the script "once off" when the file is changed. After that, node should not be running any more.

Answer (score -1):

The Visual Studio Code extension [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) appears to do what you ask.

Comment: Question is about VS CODE not Visual Studio, it's a different application, "a simple google" could have shown you that :D

Comment: @OZZIE The extension is literally called "Run On Save for Visual Studio Code".  A simple click could have shown you that.